# Run a PROC FREQ on var in dataset 1 computing correlations on a variable in dataset 2

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I'm sorry if I'm asking a stupid question, I have some experience in R and am just starting to learn SAS. In enterprise guide I'm trying to compute a correlation matrix (cramv only) for categorical variables. The problem is that explanatory variables are on dataset1 while my objective variable is on dataset2. I cannot append the obj var column to dataset one for external reasons.
Is there a way to perform the procedure without having to create another dataset?

Thank you in advance!

this is how I imagine it would work out:

```
ods output ChiSq=CRAMV; 
%put &charvar;
proc freq 
data= dataset1 dataset2
tables (&charvar) * (objvar) / chisq;
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS procedures only operate against a single dataset or view.  If you didn't want to create another dataset then you could create a view that appends the objvar column to dataset one.

Creating a view can be done with either `proc sql; create view x as...` or in a data step, `data x / view=x...`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately however my dataset is extremely big and even creating a view crashes our system...

Comment: Even if you just restrict it to the variables required?

Comment: Gonna try now, I'll tell you if I'm finally successfull, thanks!